# Infrared light out of sunlight

Tags: optics, infrared-radiation

I want to filter out any light of higher frequencies and pass only infrared. How is it done?

Comment: If this is a photography question note there is a [photo.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Infrared bandpass filters" let through only IR light.